# XeLatex Beamer font not available whereas it is for article

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex

I'm trying to use Avenir Next with my Beamer presentation.

However, for the following MWE it switches back to the default beamer font.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Avenir Next LT Pro}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Bla}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For other slides it sometimes also throws the error:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Whereas it does work for a normal article class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Avenir Next LT Pro}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Any thoughts to what could be going on?

Comment: Since the default in `beamer` is sans, and Avenir is a sans serif, use `\setsansfont` rather than `\setmainfont`.  Also see the documentation for `beamer` on `\usefonttheme{professionalfont}`.  By the way, Avenir Next is a commercial font; the site where you found it is offering a pirated copy, so expect problems.

Comment: Thanks for both your answer and pointing out that this is a commercial font. I'll get a license.